# Troubleshooting a Web Server with Timeouts?

Tags: networking, nginx, domain-name-system, web-server, web

Have a slightly strange situation that seems like a weird DNS issue.

Have a simple office website which has a very simple admin portal type area for staff to login to, and closed off by simple .htaccess.

It's running on a decent sized server behind NginX, nothing unique whatsoever and 1 of many many NginX servers running.

Users always report randomly being unable to load the login page. Hard to reproduce because its seemingly random and I can't link it to anything happening on the server (ample headroom, all resources never move over like 5% load, it's doing close to nothing), no logs indicating any issue.

However, I have reproduced it several times myself. Sometimes I'll be able to load the site in firefox, and at the same time try in Chrome and get a timeout. Or vice versa.

During these times the server is reporting absolutely nothing, which makes me think its some bizarre DNS issue. I can't explain it. It's also simply a sub-domain of our main website (separate servers) which exhibits no issues ever. Simple DNS setup as well. Does not compute.

Any ideas on an approach or how to pull anything useful out of the ether for a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

When the server is not responding, you can try to browse it using its ip address. If you can browse with ip so the problem is the dns otherwise you have other issue.

Comment: Adjusted my hosts file with a custom entry and it seemed to improve things, but did not think to test the potential weak spot directly. Good idea, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, try direct DNS route via hosts file, and also try using Google public DNS instead of relying on your ISP finding the correct site swiftly. And did you run a bunch of tests on webpagetest.org ? It may indicate whether it's DNS or just Time To First Byte issues.